# JDBC Bad format for DATE

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I am trying to read several dates from my database but under certain circumstances I get a ' java.sql.SQLException Bad format for DATE'. Here is my code :

```
Date entryDateD = res.getDate("entryDate");
```

In debug mode I see that the content of entryDateD '1996-9-15' as is in my database..
Although I would have to mention that I read other dates too from my database which I notice are of the format 'xxxx-0y-zz'. What I want to say is that in case of a month being less than 10 there is a zero added in front of it which in this case is not added. I suspect that this might have something to do with it. 
(this zero does not appear in the database itself though not only in this date but in any date)
thanx in advance :)

Comment: Stab in the dark, but what MySQL column type is entryDate?? By default a date column will generate an yyyy-mm--dd format, so the missing zero leads me to believe that the column type may be varchar or other non-date type at DB level.

Comment: omg youre actually right!!
thanx so much!! 
well it makes it look like a pretty stupid question now but it kept working satanicaly for every other input I had given it!!
Damn you Murphy's law!!

Comment: form your comment as an answer so I can accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but what MySQL column type do you have for entryDate??

By default a date type in MySQL will generate an yyyy-mm--dd format; the missing zero leads me to believe that the column type may be varchar or other non-date type at DB level.

This could be the cause of your problems at Java level...

Answer (score 2):

If you represent it as `java.util.Date`, you have the advantage of allowing the JDBC driver to worry about handling any format issues with the database.

As for how it's rendered in your display, that's up to you and your use of the `java.text.DateFormat` class.

You're doing the right thing by representing a date as `java.util.Date` in your app, but you need to understand that formatting is a separate issue from the type.

Comment: Oh no, that's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a child class of java.util.Date, called [java.sql.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

The easiest way to create a Java SQL Date is by calling the constructor with a Utility Date.

```
java.util.Date uDate = res.getDate("entryDate");
java.sql.Date sDate  = new java.sql.Date(uDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `res.getDate("entryDate")` as **YYYY-MM-DD** then you need to cast as date in your query like this:

```
SELECT
...
CAST(entryDate as DATE)as entryDate,
...
FROM your_table;
```

If you feel this is helpful then do upVote to make it useful for others.